# How to specific colour for a continuous variable in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to manually set the colour for a continuous in ggplot2. How could I do this?

This is my example code.

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = runif(100), y = runif(100), z = runif(100))

library(RColorBrewer)
cols <- rev(brewer.pal(11, 'RdYlBu'))

ggplot(df) + 
    geom_point(aes(x, y, colour = z)) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = cols)
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You're trying to apply a discrete colors (11 of them) to a continuous variable. This shall not pass. Palettes in `RColorBrewer` will generate up to 11 colors, no more.

Comment: I do not understand your question. If you want to have specific colors for specific values those need to be discrete. Otherwise you can only specify a color palette. There are several ways to do the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

```
 library(ggplot2)
    set.seed(1)
    df <- data.frame(x = runif(100), y = runif(100), z = runif(100))

    library(RColorBrewer)
    cols <- rev(brewer.pal(11, 'RdYlBu'))

    ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = z)) + 
        geom_point()+
        scale_colour_gradientn(colours = cols)
```